# Ubuntu 14.04 : Second display not detected. (Desktop computer / VGA)

Tags: 14.04, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, vga

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 installed on a desktop computer. 
This computer has a display plugged to a HDMI cable too.

I'm trying to connect a second monitor with VGA connection, but Ubuntu is not showing it inside the "displays" panel, when I hit the "Detect displays" button.

The maximum screen resolution of the VGA display is 800 X 600 pixels.

`sudo lshw -C display` gave me this:

```
  *-display               
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: GM204 [GeForce GTX 970]
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: a1
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
   resources: irq:46 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff
```

The command `xrandr` gave me this:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1360 x 768, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected primary 1360x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 700mm x 392mm
   1920x1080      60.0 +   59.9     50.0     30.0     24.0     60.1     60.0     50.0  
   1440x480       60.1  
   1360x768       59.8* 
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1280x720       59.9     59.7     50.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3  
   720x576        50.0     50.1  
   720x480        59.9     60.1  
   640x480        59.9     59.9  
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Can you please help me to solve this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the output of `sudo lshw -C display` Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: I'm not finding a VGA output on your card. Are you using an adapter?

Comment: Hi @Elder, no, I'm not using an adapter ;)

Comment: Your `xrandr`output shows 2 DVI, 1 HDMI, and 6 Displayport  ports so it appears that xrandr isn't seeing an analog  VGA 15 pin DIN

Comment: Mmm... That's really weird! I checked (physically) the VGA connection... Also: This monitor works like a charm in my notebook :I Thank you for the input anyway @Elder Geek.
Maybe is something related with the driver of my graphics card?

Comment: Please determine what version of the Nvidia driver you are using as outlined in http://askubuntu.com/questions/670485/how-to-inspect-the-currently-used-nvidia-driver-version-and-switch-it-to-another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.

Here is how: A DVI to VGA adapter plugged to the graphic card's DVI jack. (It is sold nearly 6,00 usd in my neighborhood).

The problem was that my VGA jack is in the mother board. My Graphics card doesn't have a VGA jack built in ;)

Thank you very much for the inputs @Elder Geek! :)