# How to find the proprietary drivers of my machine components?

Tags: drivers, gnome, 17.04

I would like to know if there is a repository or a away to find out the proprietary drivers of my machine components. When i do `sudo lshw` in the terminal, i see:

```
celicoo                     
    description: Notebook
    product: P65xRP (NULL)
    vendor: Notebook
    version: Not Applicable
    serial: Not Applicable
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-3.0 dmi-3.0 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=notebook family=NULL sku=NULL uuid=80FA5B34-872E-0000-0000-000000000000
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: P65xRP
       vendor: Notebook
       physical id: 0
       version: Not Applicable
       serial: Not Applicable
       slot: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
          physical id: 0
          version: 1.05.01
          date: 07/18/2016
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 15MiB
          capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd acpi usb biosbootspecification netboot uefi
     *-memory:0 UNCLAIMED
          description: Flash Memory
          physical id: 1b
          slot: System board or motherboard
          capacity: 16MiB
        *-bank UNCLAIMED
             description: FLASH Non-volatile
             product: 25Q Series
             vendor: GigaDevice
             physical id: 0
             size: 16MiB
             width: 8 bits
     *-cache:0
          description: L1 cache
          physical id: 34
          slot: L1 Cache
          size: 128KiB
          capacity: 128KiB
          capabilities: synchronous internal write-back data
          configuration: level=1
     *-cache:1
          description: L1 cache
          physical id: 35
          slot: L1 Cache
          size: 128KiB
          capacity: 128KiB
          capabilities: synchronous internal write-back instruction
          configuration: level=1
     *-cache:2
          description: L2 cache
          physical id: 36
          slot: L2 Cache
          size: 1MiB
          capacity: 1MiB
          capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
          configuration: level=2
     *-cache:3
          description: L3 cache
          physical id: 37
          slot: L3 Cache
          size: 6MiB
          capacity: 6MiB
          capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
          configuration: level=3
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 38
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz
          serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
          slot: U3E1
          size: 3472MHz
          capacity: 4005MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch epb intel_pt tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp cpufreq
          configuration: cores=4 enabledcores=4 threads=8
     *-memory:1
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 39
          slot: System board or motherboard
        *-bank:0
             description: [empty]
             physical id: 0
             slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
        *-bank:1
             description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2133 MHz (0,5 ns)
             product: CT16G4SFD8213.C16FAD
             vendor: 859B
             physical id: 1
             serial: A80F8ED3
             slot: ChannelA-DIMM1
             size: 16GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
        *-bank:2
             description: [empty]
             physical id: 2
             slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
        *-bank:3
             description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2133 MHz (0,5 ns)
             product: CT16G4SFD8213.C16FAD
             vendor: 859B
             physical id: 3
             serial: A022BF42
             slot: ChannelB-DIMM1
             size: 16GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
     *-memory:2 UNCLAIMED
          physical id: 1
     *-memory:3 UNCLAIMED
          physical id: 2
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 07
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=skl_uncore
          resources: irq:0
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Skylake PCIe Controller (x16)
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
             version: 07
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:122 ioport:e000(size=4096) memory:de000000-df0fffff ioport:c0000000(size=301989888)
           *-display
                description: VGA compatible controller
                product: GP106M [GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile]
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                version: a1
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
                configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
                resources: irq:123 memory:de000000-deffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:df000000-df07ffff
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: HD Graphics 530
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 06
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: iomemory:2f0-2ef iomemory:2f0-2ef irq:132 memory:2ffe000000-2ffeffffff memory:2fe0000000-2fefffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
        *-usb
             description: USB controller
             product: Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 31
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: iomemory:2f0-2ef irq:128 memory:2fff010000-2fff01ffff
           *-usbhost:0
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.10.0-21-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 0
                bus info: usb@1
                logical name: usb1
                version: 4.10
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=16 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:0 UNCLAIMED
                   description: Generic USB device
                   product: EgisTec_ES603
                   vendor: EgisTec
                   physical id: 7
                   bus info: usb@1:7
                   version: 2.00
                   capabilities: usb-1.10
                   configuration: maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usb:1
                   description: Bluetooth wireless interface
                   vendor: Intel Corp.
                   physical id: 8
                   bus info: usb@1:8
                   version: 0.01
                   capabilities: bluetooth usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=btusb maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
           *-usbhost:1
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.10.0-21-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@2
                logical name: usb2
                version: 4.10
                capabilities: usb-3.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=8 speed=5000Mbit/s
        *-communication
             description: Communication controller
             product: Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 31
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
             resources: iomemory:2f0-2ef irq:124 memory:2fff025000-2fff025fff
        *-storage
             description: SATA controller
             product: Sunrise Point-H SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 17
             bus info: pci@0000:00:17.0
             version: 31
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: storage msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:130 memory:df504000-df505fff memory:df507000-df5070ff ioport:f090(size=8) ioport:f080(size=4) ioport:f060(size=32) memory:df506000-df5067ff
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: f1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:16 ioport:4000(size=12288) memory:df100000-df2fffff ioport:70000000(size=1241513984)
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #5
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.4
             version: f1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:16 ioport:d000(size=4096) memory:df400000-df4fffff
           *-generic
                description: Unassigned class
                product: RTL8411B PCI Express Card Reader
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:6d:00.0
                version: 01
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom
                configuration: driver=rtsx_pci latency=0
                resources: irq:129 memory:df405000-df405fff memory:df410000-df41ffff
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0.1
                bus info: pci@0000:6d:00.1
                logical name: enp109s0f1
                version: 12
                serial: 80:fa:5b:34:87:2e
                size: 10Mbit/s
                capacity: 1Gbit/s
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8411-2_0.0.1 07/08/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
                resources: irq:131 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:df404000-df404fff memory:df400000-df403fff
        *-pci:3
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #7
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.6
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.6
             version: f1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:18 memory:df300000-df3fffff
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: Wireless 3165
                vendor: Intel Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:6e:00.0
                logical name: wlp110s0
                version: 81
                serial: ac:2b:6e:30:43:ff
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.10.0-21-generic firmware=22.391740.0 ip=192.168.0.7 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
                resources: irq:134 memory:df300000-df301fff
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 31
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master
             configuration: latency=0
        *-memory UNCLAIMED
             description: Memory controller
             product: Sunrise Point-H PMC
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             version: 31
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:df500000-df503fff
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: Sunrise Point-H HD Audio
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 31
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
             resources: iomemory:2f0-2ef iomemory:2f0-2ef irq:125 memory:2fff020000-2fff023fff memory:2fff000000-2fff00ffff
        *-serial UNCLAIMED
             description: SMBus
             product: Sunrise Point-H SMBus
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.4
             version: 31
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: iomemory:2f0-2ef memory:2fff024000-2fff0240ff ioport:f040(size=32)
     *-scsi:0
          physical id: 3
          logical name: scsi1
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: SanDisk SD8SN8U5
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sda
             version: 0000
             serial: 163000421392
             size: 476GiB (512GB)
             capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
             configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=5b282218-25bf-4e7f-b3a9-58242e67d403 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
           *-volume:0
                description: Windows FAT volume
                vendor: mkfs.fat
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sda1
                logical name: /boot/efi
                version: FAT32
                serial: 6d45-c6f7
                size: 510MiB
                capacity: 511MiB
                capabilities: boot fat initialized
                configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat mount.fstype=vfat mount.options=rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro name=EFI System Partition state=mounted
           *-volume:1
                description: EXT4 volume
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 2
                bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0,2
                logical name: /dev/sda2
                logical name: /
                version: 1.0
                serial: 5c8a8314-d4e3-49f0-8d07-633ad501d689
                size: 476GiB
                capabilities: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover 64bit extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                configuration: created=2017-05-28 19:01:43 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2017-05-30 22:11:32 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered mounted=2017-05-30 22:11:32 state=mounted
     *-scsi:1
          physical id: 4
          logical name: scsi2
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: KINGSTON SUV300S
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sdb
             version: 12.G
             serial: 50026B726401A47C
             size: 447GiB (480GB)
             capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
             configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=eba52f24-5473-4616-b93e-52a688ba1d1c logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
           *-volume:0
                description: EXT4 volume
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sdb1
                version: 1.0
                serial: 3ed63ba1-6aed-43f0-b8d0-cc2f11f1f37c
                size: 512MiB
                capabilities: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink 64bit extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                configuration: created=2017-05-28 19:30:47 filesystem=ext4 label=Partition 2 modified=2017-05-28 19:30:47 mounted=2017-05-28 19:30:47 name=EFI System Partition state=clean
           *-volume:1
                description: EXT4 volume
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 2
                bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0,2
                logical name: /dev/sdb2
                version: 1.0
                serial: ebc83c28-628f-48d5-833b-4f2ba96b49b3
                size: 446GiB
                capabilities: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink 64bit extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                configuration: created=2017-05-28 18:13:01 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2017-05-28 18:39:44 mounted=2017-05-28 18:39:45 state=clean
```

But I not finding the drivers by the name.

Thank you.

Comment: What are you looking for exactly ? I see your drivers listed "driver=nvidia" etc. What hardware and what driver information do  you want ? For the most part the drivers are part of the kernel either built in or loaded as modules depending on how the kernel and modules were compiled.

Comment: The nvidia driver I had to manually install. I would like to know where to find the available driver list according to the hardware I have. I bought this computer and it came with Windows and some other drivers installed to improve the performance of my CPU, for example ... the list had more than 15 drivers installed, however I missed this list.

Comment: Linux is not windows and the drivers for your CPU, hard drive, RAM, etc you are asking about are compiled into the kernel. For the nvidia driver and available drivers look in software center - https://askubuntu.com/questions/670485/how-to-inspect-the-currently-used-nvidia-driver-version-and-switch-it-to-another

Comment: See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/670485/how-to-inspect-the-currently-used-nvidia-driver-version-and-switch-it-to-another and technical documentation on the linux kernel - http://freesoftwaremagazine.com/articles/drivers_linux/ and http://www.haifux.org/lectures/86-sil/kernel-modules-drivers/kernel-modules-drivers.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proprietary drivers for Ubuntu (desktop systems) may be needed only for graphics (Nvidia or AMD) and Broadcom wireless adapters.

You have the Nvidia drivers installed.

Nothing else is needed. All other drivers are in the Linux kernel.

Comment: Really? This is awesome. But what about drivers to speed up or use the CPU better? Like Intel Rapid Storage?

Comment: The proprietry nvidia and AMD drivers are not always needed, I hardly ever use them. Broadcom depends as well. In general propierty drivers are only needed if open source drivers are unavailable for any variety of reasons or have poor performance.

Comment: I changed it to "may be needed" before you wrote the comment ))

Comment: @Celo - google is your friend - http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/memory-and-storage/000021648.html

Comment: @Celo You do not need any drivers to "use the CPU better".