# How do I know which NVIDIA driver I need?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 19.10

I need to use NVIDIA drivers, and I used the `nvidia-smi` command to check which NVIDIA I have, but this was the output:

```
Command 'nvidia-smi' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install nvidia-utils-390  # version 390.138-0ubuntu0.19.10.1, or
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-440  # version 440.100-0ubuntu0.19.10.1
sudo apt install nvidia-340        # version 340.107-0ubuntu7
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-430  # version 430.50-0ubuntu2
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-435  # version 435.21-0ubuntu2
```

Any clue which one to install?

I am running on Ubuntu Live on a [Lenovo Ideapad 130S (11)](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/ideapad/ideapad-100-series/Lenovo-ideapad-S130-11IGM/p/88IP10S1075), but let me know if you need any more information about my system

Answer (score 26):

To check which is the recommended driver for your Nvidia card run:

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
```

If you want to install the driver automatically, run :

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

If you want to install a specific driver version (410, 440...), run:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-<driver number>
```

Once the installation is finished, restart your PC.
Then run `prime-select query` to check which graphic card is being used by your device.

If you want to change the graphic card used by your PC, run : `sudo prime-select <intel/ nvidia>`; choose between Nvidia and Intel graphic cards.
After that, restart your PC to apply changes

Comment: `$ sudo apt install nvidia-535`
`Reading package lists... Done`
`Building dependency tree       `
`Reading state information... Done`
`E: Unable to locate package nvidia-535`

so it doesn't help

Comment: you can also use the GUI with :
```sudo kubuntu-driver-manager```