# My laptop sometimes can't boot to X when it isn't on AC power

Tags: boot, nvidia, 22.04

I have a 2021 ROG Zephyrus G14 laptop with Ubuntu 22.04, which I usually run while plugged into the wall. When it's not plugged it and I try to boot it, the boot process sometimes doesn't make it all the way to the graphical login screen. Instead, just before the point where the graphical login screen would usually be displayed, I see a screenful of cryptic lines about "nouveau", like this:

```
Jul 31 08:42:17 Frost kernel: [   15.762402] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: mc: intr 00000040
Jul 31 08:42:17 Frost kernel: [   15.762542] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: mc: intr 00000040
Jul 31 08:42:17 Frost kernel: [   15.762679] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: mc: intr 00000040
Jul 31 08:42:17 Frost kernel: [   15.762817] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: mc: intr 00000040
Jul 31 08:42:17 Frost kernel: [   15.762955] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: mc: intr 00000040
Jul 31 08:42:17 Frost kernel: [   15.763087] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: mc: intr 00000040
Jul 31 08:42:17 Frost kernel: [   15.763230] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: mc: intr 00000040
Jul 31 08:42:17 Frost kernel: [   15.763367] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: mc: intr 00000040
```

I can switch to a TTY and log into `zsh` there, but after maybe 30 seconds that too gets filled with these messages and apparently stops responding to input. None of those lines seems to be left in `/var/log/dmesg*` afterwards when I boot up properly again.

How can I start debugging this? I have an RTX 3060.

Here are some example `journalctl` logs from an unsucessful boot (not plugged in) and a successful boot (plugged in): https://gist.github.com/Kodiologist/a7136bf44a814e113aa51c9ebe09292e

Comment: " I see a screenful of cryptic dmesg lines about nouveau. " and we need to guess what those lines are? Please copy/paste at least the 1st one stating an error. "None of those lines seem to be left in /var/log/dmesg* afterwards when I boot up properly again." of course not, dmesg is not intended for that. check /var/log/ for the last couple of files written. If unsure do a `grep` with parts of the messages you see.

Comment: Maybe your laptop needs a new battery.

Comment: @Rinzwind How do I copy and paste messages that aren't in any of `/var/log/dmesg*`? I grepped for them and didn't find them. That's why I said they're not there.

Comment: why do you keep repeating dmesg? again: NOT the correct file. /var/log/sysslog will have your boot log.

Comment: @Rinzwind Because you didn't previously indicate what the correct file was. But looking in `/var/log/syslog`, I indeed see lines like `Jul 31 08:42:17 Frost kernel: [   15.757635] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: mc: intr 00000040`, which are what I saw before. I'll put some in the question.

Comment: @Kodiologist Actually he did, right there in the first comment: *"of course not, dmesg is not intended for that. check /var/log/ for the last couple of files written"*. Now, regarding your issue: 1. Disable Secure Boot in UEFI 2. Install the recommended Nvidia drivers (Software & Updates > Additional Drivers), reboot.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Look at the portion you quoted closely. He said `/var/log/` in his first comment, and only mentioned `/var/log/syslog` in the second. But, more importantly, it looks like you solved my problem, so thank you kindly.

Answer (score 1):

I think [@ChanganAuto's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1421191/my-laptop-sometimes-cant-boot-to-x-when-it-isnt-on-ac-power#comment2473595_1421191) did it:

> [...] Now, regarding your issue: 1. Disable Secure Boot in UEFI 2. Install the recommended Nvidia drivers (Software & Updates > Additional Drivers), reboot.

I used `ubuntu-drivers devices` (from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1258909)) to identify the recommended version of the proprietary Nvidia driver for my system (namely `nvidia-driver-515`) and installed it (after disabling Secure Boot), and I can no longer reproduce the problem.