# How to install cuda10.1？Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled

Tags: cuda

[image]

[image]

[image]

First of all, my graphics card is MTT S80. A friend suggested using the CPU version of pytorch, but when I run deep learning code, it prompts me:`Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled`, so I think I should still install CUDA. According to the prompts, it seems that my system supports the highest version 10.1. However, when I searched the official website, I found that CUDA 10.1 supports the highest version 18.04 of Ubuntu, while my Ubuntu version is 20.04. So what should I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Command "nvidia-smi" not found, but can be installed with:](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1501904/command-nvidia-smi-not-found-but-can-be-installed-with)

Comment: 1501904 answer is that your card is not CUDA compatible.

Comment: The CUDA software library needs to connect to CUDA cores on a Nvidia card. No other GPU manufacturer has CUDA cores. Anyway, "Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled" means it's a problem with PyTorch, not the CUDA library on Ubuntu. You could `pip install` the GPU version of PyTorch to solve this error, but you will get another error and it will never work until you buy a Nvidia card.