# Ubuntu 23.10 does not start after running CHKDSK from Windows in a unused partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 23.10, disk-check

In my system I have two SDDs:

1. with Ubuntu 23.10 and Windows 11
2. two main partitions: one ext4 for `/home` and one NTFS for generic storage in Windows

Until few weeks ago I was able to mount the "storage" partition in Ubuntu, then it refused to mount it anymore and reading the answers here I started Windows (for 99% of time I run Ubuntu only) and I ran chkdsk on the "storage" partition.

After rebooting, Ubuntu does not start anymore.
It hangs after mounting the snap stuff.

The last message is: "Press ctrl+c to cancel the disk checking" (not sure about the exact words - it is in Italian). But nothing happens neither pressing ctrl+c nor waiting for hours.

What I tried:

- boot from an older kernel
- boot in recovery mode and run `fsck`: if I confirm to remount the drives it fails because they are mounted, if I do not confirm it does nothing
- boot in recovery mode and manually run `fsck` on all Linux partitions, no errors found
- boot in recovery mode and run `badblocks -sv` on both drives, no errors found
- edit the grub cmdline adding `fsck. mode=skip`: it actually does not show the message but still freezes at the same point
- change the console (i.e. alt+f6), log in and try to manually start gnome with `exec gnome-session`: it requests again the login
- change the console (i.e. alt+f6), log in and try to manually start gnome with `sudo /etc/init.d/gdm3 start`: it says: "Starting gdm3 (via systemctl): gdm3.service" but nothing else happens (the same in I start the service directly)
- check in `/etc/fstab` for the Windows partition: as expected is not there, as I mount it manually only when needed
- run `apt update && apt upgrade`
- from the recovery menu select "check for damaged packages"

Here some output of `dmesg` that sounds suspicious (I cannot post here the whole content) but I'm not sure if they are related to the current issue:

```
...
[   12.014265] vboxdrv: Found 32 processor cores/threads
[   12.014372] ================================================================================
[   12.014373] UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in /tmp/vbox.0/common/log/log.c:1791:41
[   12.014374] index 1 is out of range for type 'uint32_t [1]'
[   12.014375] CPU: 6 PID: 2161 Comm: modprobe Tainted: P           OE      6.5.0-15-generic #15-Ubuntu
[   12.014377] Hardware name: ASUS System Product Name/ROG STRIX X670E-E GAMING WIFI, BIOS 0705 10/05/2022
[   12.014378] Call Trace:
[   12.014379]  <TASK>
[   12.014381]  dump_stack_lvl+0x48/0x70
[   12.014385]  dump_stack+0x10/0x20
[   12.014387]  __ubsan_handle_out_of_bounds+0xc6/0x110
[   12.014391]  VBoxHost_RTLogGroupSettings+0x49f/0x4c0 [vboxdrv]
[   12.014404]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0x7f
[   12.014407]  ? rtR0MemAllocEx+0x57/0xd0 [vboxdrv]
[   12.014419]  VBoxHost_RTLogCreateExV+0x297/0x4a0 [vboxdrv]
[   12.014433]  VBoxHost_RTLogCreate+0x6f/0xb0 [vboxdrv]
[   12.014446]  ? rtR0MemAllocEx+0x57/0xd0 [vboxdrv]
[   12.014457]  supdrvInitDevExt+0x59/0x330 [vboxdrv]
[   12.014471]  VBoxDrvLinuxInit+0x87/0xff0 [vboxdrv]
[   12.014483]  ? __pfx_VBoxDrvLinuxInit+0x10/0x10 [vboxdrv]
[   12.014494]  do_one_initcall+0x5b/0x340
[   12.014498]  do_init_module+0x91/0x290
[   12.014501]  load_module+0xba1/0xcf0
[   12.014505]  init_module_from_file+0x96/0x100
[   12.014507]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0x7f
[   12.014508]  ? init_module_from_file+0x96/0x100
[   12.014511]  idempotent_init_module+0x11c/0x2b0
[   12.014514]  __x64_sys_finit_module+0x64/0xd0
[   12.014516]  do_syscall_64+0x59/0x90
[   12.014518]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0x7f
[   12.014519]  ? ext4_llseek+0xc3/0x130
[   12.014522]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0x7f
[   12.014523]  ? ksys_lseek+0x7d/0xd0
[   12.014525]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0x7f
[   12.014526]  ? exit_to_user_mode_prepare+0x30/0xb0
[   12.014528]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0x7f
[   12.014529]  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x37/0x60
[   12.014532]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0x7f
[   12.014533]  ? do_syscall_64+0x68/0x90
[   12.014534]  ? irqentry_exit+0x43/0x50
[   12.014535]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0x7f
[   12.014536]  ? exc_page_fault+0x94/0x1b0
[   12.014537]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x6e/0xd8
[   12.014539] RIP: 0033:0x7f45ca925cfd
[   12.014556] Code: ff c3 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 90 f3 0f 1e fa 48 89 f8 48 89 f7 48 89 d6 48 89 ca 4d 89 c2 4d 89 c8 4c 8b 4c 24 08 0f 05 <48> 3d 01 f0 ff ff 73 01 c3 48 8b 0d eb 80 0d 00 f7 d8 64 89 01 48
[   12.014557] RSP: 002b:00007fff8e6d97a8 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000139
[   12.014559] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000563dedd68ae0 RCX: 00007f45ca925cfd
[   12.014560] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000563debe56727 RDI: 0000000000000003
[   12.014560] RBP: 0000563debe56727 R08: 0000000000000040 R09: 00007fff8e6d98b0
[   12.014561] R10: ffffffffffffffc0 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000000000040000
[   12.014562] R13: 0000563dedd68460 R14: 0000563dedd699d0 R15: 0000563dedd68dc0
[   12.014564]  </TASK>
[   12.014565] ================================================================================
[   12.014572] ================================================================================
[   12.014573] UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in /tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.c:399:33
[   12.014574] index 1 is out of range for type 'page *[1]'
[   12.014574] CPU: 6 PID: 2161 Comm: modprobe Tainted: P           OE      6.5.0-15-generic #15-Ubuntu
[   12.014576] Hardware name: ASUS System Product Name/ROG STRIX X670E-E GAMING WIFI, BIOS 0705 10/05/2022
[   12.014576] Call Trace:
[   12.014577]  <TASK>
[   12.014577]  dump_stack_lvl+0x48/0x70
[   12.014579]  dump_stack+0x10/0x20
[   12.014580]  __ubsan_handle_out_of_bounds+0xc6/0x110
[   12.014582]  rtR0MemObjLinuxAllocPages+0x31c/0x330 [vboxdrv]
[   12.014595]  rtR0MemObjNativeAllocCont+0x5f/0x130 [vboxdrv]
[   12.014607]  VBoxHost_RTR0MemObjAllocContTag+0x4e/0xa0 [vboxdrv]
[   12.014620]  supdrvGipCreate+0x66/0xdf0 [vboxdrv]
[   12.014632]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0x7f
[   12.014633]  ? rtR0MemAllocEx+0x57/0xd0 [vboxdrv]
[   12.014645]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0x7f
[   12.014647]  supdrvInitDevExt+0x14d/0x330 [vboxdrv]
[   12.014659]  VBoxDrvLinuxInit+0x87/0xff0 [vboxdrv]
[   12.014670]  ? __pfx_VBoxDrvLinuxInit+0x10/0x10 [vboxdrv]
[   12.014681]  do_one_initcall+0x5b/0x340
[   12.014684]  do_init_module+0x91/0x290
[   12.014686]  load_module+0xba1/0xcf0
[   12.014689]  init_module_from_file+0x96/0x100
[   12.014691]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0x7f
[   12.014692]  ? init_module_from_file+0x96/0x100
[   12.014695]  idempotent_init_module+0x11c/0x2b0
[   12.014698]  __x64_sys_finit_module+0x64/0xd0
[   12.014700]  do_syscall_64+0x59/0x90
[   12.014701]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0x7f
[   12.014702]  ? ext4_llseek+0xc3/0x130
[   12.014704]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0x7f
[   12.014705]  ? ksys_lseek+0x7d/0xd0
[   12.014706]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0x7f
[   12.014707]  ? exit_to_user_mode_prepare+0x30/0xb0
[   12.014709]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0x7f
[   12.014710]  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x37/0x60
[   12.014711]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0x7f
[   12.014712]  ? do_syscall_64+0x68/0x90
[   12.014713]  ? irqentry_exit+0x43/0x50
[   12.014714]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0x7f
[   12.014715]  ? exc_page_fault+0x94/0x1b0
[   12.014717]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x6e/0xd8
[   12.014718] RIP: 0033:0x7f45ca925cfd
[   12.014720] Code: ff c3 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 90 f3 0f 1e fa 48 89 f8 48 89 f7 48 89 d6 48 89 ca 4d 89 c2 4d 89 c8 4c 8b 4c 24 08 0f 05 <48> 3d 01 f0 ff ff 73 01 c3 48 8b 0d eb 80 0d 00 f7 d8 64 89 01 48
[   12.014721] RSP: 002b:00007fff8e6d97a8 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000139
[   12.014722] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000563dedd68ae0 RCX: 00007f45ca925cfd
[   12.014723] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000563debe56727 RDI: 0000000000000003
[   12.014723] RBP: 0000563debe56727 R08: 0000000000000040 R09: 00007fff8e6d98b0
[   12.014724] R10: ffffffffffffffc0 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000000000040000
[   12.014724] R13: 0000563dedd68460 R14: 0000563dedd699d0 R15: 0000563dedd68dc0
[   12.014727]  </TASK>
[   12.014727] ================================================================================
[   12.014728] ================================================================================
[   12.014728] UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in /tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.c:596:45
[   12.014729] index 3 is out of range for type 'page *[1]'
[   12.014729] CPU: 6 PID: 2161 Comm: modprobe Tainted: P           OE      6.5.0-15-generic #15-Ubuntu
[   12.014730] Hardware name: ASUS System Product Name/ROG STRIX X670E-E GAMING WIFI, BIOS 0705 10/05/2022
[   12.014731] Call Trace:
[   12.014731]  <TASK>
[   12.014732]  dump_stack_lvl+0x48/0x70
[   12.014733]  dump_stack+0x10/0x20
[   12.014735]  __ubsan_handle_out_of_bounds+0xc6/0x110
[   12.014737]  rtR0MemObjLinuxVMap+0xb7/0xc0 [vboxdrv]
[   12.014749]  rtR0MemObjNativeAllocCont+0x76/0x130 [vboxdrv]
[   12.014760]  VBoxHost_RTR0MemObjAllocContTag+0x4e/0xa0 [vboxdrv]
[   12.014772]  supdrvGipCreate+0x66/0xdf0 [vboxdrv]
[   12.014783]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0x7f
[   12.014784]  ? rtR0MemAllocEx+0x57/0xd0 [vboxdrv]
[   12.014795]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0x7f
[   12.014797]  supdrvInitDevExt+0x14d/0x330 [vboxdrv]
[   12.014808]  VBoxDrvLinuxInit+0x87/0xff0 [vboxdrv]
[   12.014819]  ? __pfx_VBoxDrvLinuxInit+0x10/0x10 [vboxdrv]
[   12.014830]  do_one_initcall+0x5b/0x340
[   12.014833]  do_init_module+0x91/0x290
[   12.014835]  load_module+0xba1/0xcf0
[   12.014839]  init_module_from_file+0x96/0x100
[   12.014840]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0x7f
[   12.014841]  ? init_module_from_file+0x96/0x100
[   12.014844]  idempotent_init_module+0x11c/0x2b0
[   12.014847]  __x64_sys_finit_module+0x64/0xd0
[   12.014849]  do_syscall_64+0x59/0x90
[   12.014850]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0x7f
[   12.014851]  ? ext4_llseek+0xc3/0x130
[   12.014853]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0x7f
[   12.014854]  ? ksys_lseek+0x7d/0xd0
[   12.014855]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0x7f
[   12.014856]  ? exit_to_user_mode_prepare+0x30/0xb0
[   12.014858]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0x7f
[   12.014859]  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x37/0x60
[   12.014860]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0x7f
[   12.014861]  ? do_syscall_64+0x68/0x90
[   12.014862]  ? irqentry_exit+0x43/0x50
[   12.014863]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0x7f
[   12.014864]  ? exc_page_fault+0x94/0x1b0
[   12.014865]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x6e/0xd8
[   12.014866] RIP: 0033:0x7f45ca925cfd
[   12.014868] Code: ff c3 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 90 f3 0f 1e fa 48 89 f8 48 89 f7 48 89 d6 48 89 ca 4d 89 c2 4d 89 c8 4c 8b 4c 24 08 0f 05 <48> 3d 01 f0 ff ff 73 01 c3 48 8b 0d eb 80 0d 00 f7 d8 64 89 01 48
[   12.014869] RSP: 002b:00007fff8e6d97a8 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000139
[   12.014870] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000563dedd68ae0 RCX: 00007f45ca925cfd
[   12.014871] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000563debe56727 RDI: 0000000000000003
[   12.014871] RBP: 0000563debe56727 R08: 0000000000000040 R09: 00007fff8e6d98b0
[   12.014872] R10: ffffffffffffffc0 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000000000040000
[   12.014872] R13: 0000563dedd68460 R14: 0000563dedd699d0 R15: 0000563dedd68dc0
[   12.014875]  </TASK>
[   12.014875] ================================================================================
[   12.014878] ================================================================================
[   12.014878] UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in /tmp/vbox.0/SUPDrvGip.c:1956:44
[   12.014879] index 2 is out of range for type 'SUPGIPCPU [1]'
[   12.014879] CPU: 6 PID: 2161 Comm: modprobe Tainted: P           OE      6.5.0-15-generic #15-Ubuntu
[   12.014880] Hardware name: ASUS System Product Name/ROG STRIX X670E-E GAMING WIFI, BIOS 0705 10/05/2022
[   12.014881] Call Trace:
[   12.014881]  <TASK>
[   12.014881]  dump_stack_lvl+0x48/0x70
[   12.014883]  dump_stack+0x10/0x20
[   12.014884]  __ubsan_handle_out_of_bounds+0xc6/0x110
[   12.014886]  supdrvGipCreate+0xda7/0xdf0 [vboxdrv]
[   12.014897]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0x7f
[   12.014899]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0x7f
[   12.014901]  supdrvInitDevExt+0x14d/0x330 [vboxdrv]
[   12.014912]  VBoxDrvLinuxInit+0x87/0xff0 [vboxdrv]
[   12.014923]  ? __pfx_VBoxDrvLinuxInit+0x10/0x10 [vboxdrv]
[   12.014934]  do_one_initcall+0x5b/0x340
[   12.014937]  do_init_module+0x91/0x290
[   12.014938]  load_module+0xba1/0xcf0
[   12.014942]  init_module_from_file+0x96/0x100
[   12.014943]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0x7f
[   12.014944]  ? init_module_from_file+0x96/0x100
[   12.014948]  idempotent_init_module+0x11c/0x2b0
[   12.014951]  __x64_sys_finit_module+0x64/0xd0
[   12.014953]  do_syscall_64+0x59/0x90
[   12.014954]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0x7f
[   12.014955]  ? ext4_llseek+0xc3/0x130
[   12.014956]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0x7f
[   12.014957]  ? ksys_lseek+0x7d/0xd0
[   12.014959]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0x7f
[   12.014960]  ? exit_to_user_mode_prepare+0x30/0xb0
[   12.014961]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0x7f
[   12.014962]  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x37/0x60
[   12.014963]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0x7f
[   12.014964]  ? do_syscall_64+0x68/0x90
[   12.014965]  ? irqentry_exit+0x43/0x50
[   12.014966]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0x7f
[   12.014967]  ? exc_page_fault+0x94/0x1b0
[   12.014969]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x6e/0xd8
[   12.014970] RIP: 0033:0x7f45ca925cfd
[   12.014972] Code: ff c3 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 90 f3 0f 1e fa 48 89 f8 48 89 f7 48 89 d6 48 89 ca 4d 89 c2 4d 89 c8 4c 8b 4c 24 08 0f 05 <48> 3d 01 f0 ff ff 73 01 c3 48 8b 0d eb 80 0d 00 f7 d8 64 89 01 48
[   12.014972] RSP: 002b:00007fff8e6d97a8 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000139
[   12.014973] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000563dedd68ae0 RCX: 00007f45ca925cfd
[   12.014974] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000563debe56727 RDI: 0000000000000003
[   12.014974] RBP: 0000563debe56727 R08: 0000000000000040 R09: 00007fff8e6d98b0
[   12.014975] R10: ffffffffffffffc0 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000000000040000
[   12.014976] R13: 0000563dedd68460 R14: 0000563dedd699d0 R15: 0000563dedd68dc0
[   12.014978]  </TASK>
[   12.014978] ================================================================================
[   12.032481] ================================================================================
...
[  287.273183] audit: type=1400 audit(1706804289.805:217): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" class="cap" profile="/snap/snapd/20671/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=19619 comm="snap-confine" capability=38  capname="perfmon"
[  318.777572] audit: type=1400 audit(1706804321.309:218): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" class="cap" profile="/snap/snapd/20671/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=21504 comm="snap-confine" capability=12  capname="net_admin"
[  318.777586] audit: type=1400 audit(1706804321.309:219): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" class="cap" profile="/snap/snapd/20671/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=21504 comm="snap-confine" capability=38  capname="perfmon"
[  670.069858] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[  670.069868] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[  670.069872] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  765.074203] traps: gdm3[54970] trap int3 ip:7f1105f46a0d sp:7ffec7bf8e60 error:0 in libglib-2.0.so.0.7800.0[7f1105f02000+9a000]
[  766.434234] traps: gdm3[55036] trap int3 ip:7fb10cc8fa0d sp:7fffc1138010 error:0 in libglib-2.0.so.0.7800.0[7fb10cc4b000+9a000]
[  767.970139] traps: gdm3[55180] trap int3 ip:7f1048e37a0d sp:7ffe6f224cb0 error:0 in libglib-2.0.so.0.7800.0[7f1048df3000+9a000]
[  769.446560] traps: gdm3[55328] trap int3 ip:7fcb70fbea0d sp:7ffe712cd6c0 error:0 in libglib-2.0.so.0.7800.0[7fcb70f7a000+9a000]
[  770.934558] traps: gdm3[55513] trap int3 ip:7efdf4ae4a0d sp:7ffc701d29f0 error:0 in libglib-2.0.so.0.7800.0[7efdf4aa0000+9a000]
```

I'm running out of ideas.
What should I do to find out why my system refuses to start and how to fix it?

### UPDATE

After the comment of DanielT.
I'm using VirtualBox almost daily without any problem. Anyway, in order to try to boot again into Gnome, I tried to remove it. Actually I had to remove the `virtualbox-7.0` package.

Unfortunately the behavior is the same.
Here the current errors:

```
$ sudo dmesg -l err
[    0.364620] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.GPP7.UP00.DP40.UP00.DP68], AE_NOT_FOUND (20230331/dswload2-162)
[    0.364632] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20230331/psobject-220)
[    6.311861] hub 10-0:1.0: config failed, hub doesn't have any ports! (err -19)
[   10.471789] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: WRT: Invalid buffer destination

[   11.910476] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: WRT: Invalid buffer destination
[   13.921769] ================================================================================
[   13.921783] UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/525.147.05/build/nvidia-uvm/uvm_pmm_gpu.c:2323:28
[   13.921793] index 0 is out of range for type 'uvm_gpu_chunk_t *[*]'
[   13.922137] ================================================================================
[   13.922146] ================================================================================
[   13.922152] UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/525.147.05/build/nvidia-uvm/uvm_pmm_gpu.c:2003:44
[   13.922161] index 0 is out of range for type 'uvm_gpu_chunk_t *[*]'
[   13.922427] ================================================================================
[   13.922434] ================================================================================
[   13.922440] UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/525.147.05/build/nvidia-uvm/uvm_pmm_gpu.c:713:68
[   13.922448] index 0 is out of range for type 'uvm_gpu_chunk_t *[*]'
[   13.922722] ================================================================================
[   13.922729] ================================================================================
[   13.922735] UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/525.147.05/build/nvidia-uvm/uvm_pmm_gpu.c:2009:63
[   13.922743] index 1 is out of range for type 'uvm_gpu_chunk_t *[*]'
[   13.923001] ================================================================================
[   13.942298] ================================================================================
[   13.942307] UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/525.147.05/build/nvidia-uvm/uvm_mmu.c:425:17
[   13.942316] index 0 is out of range for type 'uvm_page_directory_t *[*]'
[   13.942619] ================================================================================
[   13.942630] ================================================================================
[   13.942636] UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/525.147.05/build/nvidia-uvm/uvm_mmu.c:411:51
[   13.942644] index 16 is out of range for type 'uvm_page_directory_t *[*]'
[   13.942910] ================================================================================
[   14.025724] ================================================================================
[   14.025738] UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/525.147.05/build/nvidia-uvm/uvm_mmu.c:425:17
[   14.025748] index 57 is out of range for type 'uvm_page_directory_t *[*]'
[   14.026005] ================================================================================
[   14.063684] ================================================================================
[   14.063688] UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/525.147.05/build/nvidia-uvm/uvm_pmm_gpu.c:2563:71
[   14.063690] index 0 is out of range for type 'uvm_gpu_chunk_t *[*]'
[   14.064242] ================================================================================
[   14.064245] ================================================================================
[   14.064246] UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/525.147.05/build/nvidia-uvm/uvm_pmm_gpu.c:795:45
[   14.064248] index 0 is out of range for type 'uvm_gpu_chunk_t *[*]'
[   14.064748] ================================================================================
[   14.064750] ================================================================================
[   14.064751] UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/525.147.05/build/nvidia-uvm/uvm_pmm_gpu.c:822:39
[   14.064752] index 0 is out of range for type 'uvm_gpu_chunk_t *[*]'
[   14.065223] ================================================================================
```

They are about Nvidia - I don't understand if (and how) they can be related with my issue.

### UPDATE 2

I didn't mess with Nvidia drivers since several months.
Anyway:

```
$ nvidia-smi
Thu Feb  1 20:41:44 2024       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 525.147.05   Driver Version: 525.147.05   CUDA Version: 12.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   30C    P8    13W / 320W |      1MiB / 16376MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

And it seems correct to me.
Ubuntu says:

```
$ ubuntu-drivers devices
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00002704sv0000196Esd000013BCbc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : AD103 [GeForce RTX 4080]
driver   : nvidia-driver-545 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-535-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-525 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-525-open - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-535-server-open - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-525-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-535 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-545-open - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-535-open - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

I tried `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` but after rebooting... it still hangs claiming to check the filesystem errors, but it does nothing actually.

Comment: VirtualBox doesn't work on 23.10. There is a thread and unofficial solution at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virtualbox/+bug/2037082 . If you're not using it, you should `sudo apt purge virtualbox-dkms`

Comment: @DanielT question updated!

Comment: Did you install the right version of the Nvidia driver? https://askubuntu.com/q/1258904/1004020

Comment: @DanielT I think so, please see the second update

Comment: By the way, the nvidia error messages *seem* harmless: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/ubsan-array-index-out-of-bounds-complaints-in-newer-kernels/271705/7

Comment: What about these lines? `traps: gdm3[2723] trap int3 ip:7fa494fe3a0d sp:7ffd8a525df0 error:0 in libglib-2.0.so.0.7800.0[7fa494f9f000+9a000]`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if and how my activity on Windows could have raised the issue in Ubuntu, but I found the solution inspecting `/var/log/syslog`:

> 2024-02-02T15:39:46.874574+01:00 mark gdm3: Gdm: GdmSession: no session desktop files installed, aborting...

Hence I wild guessed a:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-session
```

and it fixed the issue.