# Problem with Nvidia-drivers in Ubuntu 22.04.3. LTS

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I have Nvidia drivers (GeForce GTX 1660 SUPER) on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. Everything was functioning properly with the Nvidia drivers until recently when problems started to arise.

In an attempt to resolve the issue, I executed the purge command to completely remove all Nvidia drivers from my system. Following this, I reinstalled the drivers using the auto-installation feature for Ubuntu drivers, however despite these efforts the problem persists.

Alongside the Nvidia driver issues, I have also experienced problems with YouTube sound and other applications such as Anydesk, which are not functioning correctly.

I have attached the images of specific drivers, although I have tried using proprietary, tested current drivers and issues.

Current drivers:

[image: current drivers]

Results of `nvidia-smi`:

[image: nvidia-smi]

Comment: can you share output of **lsmod | grep nvidia**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I know which NVIDIA driver I need?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1258904/how-do-i-know-which-nvidia-driver-i-need)

Comment: Did a recent update install the 6.5 kernel on your system?

Comment: Dear @obayhan no output is generated after executing  lsmod | grep nvidia

Comment: @OrganicMarble 6.5.0-1014-oracle showing after executing "uname -r"

Comment: There have been many reports here of nvidia driver issues with the 6.5 kernel. Try booting into an older kernel at the grub screen, and see if the drivers work then.

Comment: @NagendraPrasad then your nvidia driver is not loaded. Can you please share dmesg output?

Comment: @obayhan dmesg: read kernel buffer failed: Operation not permitted

Comment: @NagendraPrasad sudo dmesg. Also please share it in your question. Wont fit here (: