# Does using upgrade nvidia-driver present the danger of updating to an unsupported driver?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, upgrade, gpu-driver

I need to upgrade my nvidia-driver in my two ubuntu machines.

I am thinking of using

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade nvidia-driver
```

but I also know there is the option of searching for a driver in nvidia homepage and downloading manually.

My question is, if I use `upgrade` is there a risk that I install a driver that is not adequate for my GPU?
(My two ubuntu machine use different GPU card models)

Comment: It is not recommended to use the `nvidia-driver` metapackage because according to https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=nvidia-driver , it will be removed on newer Ubuntu versions. The "searching for a driver in nvidia homepage" is not recommended either. The recommended method is indeed to select the nvidia driver by its version number: https://askubuntu.com/a/1258909/1004020

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work.