# Ubuntu boot up grey screen when Nvidia Driver is installed

Tags: nvidia, acpi

as the title suggest, as soon as I install a nvidia driver it only boots to a grey screen. If i purge the driver it boots again normal. Its a fresh ubuntu install with only Ubuntu sdd connected.

Hardware:
RTX 3090
ASUS B760-I

Drivers tried:
545
530
470

Bootparameters: nomodeset noplymouth

Weird thing is, when i go into recovery or press ctrl+alt+f2 while i see the grey screen nvidia-smi tells me the driver & cuda is working.

I blacklisted nouveau.
I updated Bios to newest version.

I really do not know what i  could do next, help would be appreciated.

here are the error logs:

```
Feb 10 12:31:41 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: Booted with the nomodeset parameter. Only the system framebuffer will be available
Feb 10 12:31:41 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   #1  #3  #5  #7  #9 #11 #13 #15
Feb 10 12:31:41 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: ENERGY_PERF_BIAS: Set to 'normal', was 'performance'
Feb 10 12:31:41 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: Driver imsttfb not loading because of nomodeset parameter
Feb 10 12:31:41 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: Driver asiliantfb not loading because of nomodeset parameter
Feb 10 12:31:41 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: hpet_acpi_add: no address or irqs in _CRS
Feb 10 12:31:41 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: device-mapper: core: CONFIG_IMA_DISABLE_HTABLE is disabled. Duplicate IMA measurements will not be recorded in the IMA log.
Feb 10 12:31:41 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: platform eisa.0: EISA: Cannot allocate resource for mainboard
Feb 10 12:31:41 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 1
Feb 10 12:31:41 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 2
Feb 10 12:31:41 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 3
Feb 10 12:31:41 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 4
Feb 10 12:31:41 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 5
Feb 10 12:31:41 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 6
Feb 10 12:31:41 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 7
Feb 10 12:31:41 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 8
Feb 10 12:31:41 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: acpi PNP0C14:05: duplicate WMI GUID 97845ED0-4E6D-11DE-8A39-0800200C9A66 (first instance was on PNP0C14:02)
Feb 10 12:31:41 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: usb: port power management may be unreliable
Feb 10 12:31:41 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: ata6.00: NCQ Send/Recv Log not supported
Feb 10 12:31:41 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: ata6.00: NCQ Send/Recv Log not supported
Feb 10 12:31:41 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: systemd[1]: memfd_create() called without MFD_EXEC or MFD_NOEXEC_SEAL set
Feb 10 12:31:41 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: block sda: the capability attribute has been deprecated.
Feb 10 12:31:41 felix-ubuntu-lm systemd-udevd[480]: sda: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/sda' failed with exit code 1.
Feb 10 12:31:41 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: asus_wmi: Failed to get WMI notify code: AE_NOT_FOUND
Feb 10 12:31:41 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: asus_wmi: Failed to get event during flush: -5
Feb 10 12:31:41 felix-ubuntu-lm systemd-udevd[490]: sda2: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/sda2' failed with exit code 1.
Feb 10 12:31:41 felix-ubuntu-lm systemd-udevd[475]: dm-0: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/dm-0' failed with exit code 1.
Feb 10 12:31:41 felix-ubuntu-lm systemd-udevd[480]: sda1: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/sda1' failed with exit code 1.
Feb 10 12:31:41 felix-ubuntu-lm systemd-udevd[494]: dm-1: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/dm-1' failed with exit code 1.
Feb 10 12:31:41 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
Feb 10 12:31:41 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: thermal thermal_zone1: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
Feb 10 12:31:41 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Invalid buffer destination
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: nvidia: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: nvidia: module license taints kernel.
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: 
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  545.23.08  Mon Nov  6 23:49:37 UTC 2023
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: nvidia_uvm: module uses symbols nvUvmInterfaceDisableAccessCntr from proprietary module nvidia, inheriting taint.
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: ACPI Warning: \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20230331/nsarguments-61)
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230331/dsfield-184)
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20230331/dswload2-477)
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: 
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_DSM]
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: 
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: Initialized Arguments for Method [_DSM]:  (4 arguments defined for method invocation)
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg0:   000000007bb83016 <Obj>           Buffer(16) 75 0B A5 D4 C7 65 F7 46
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg1:   00000000152e7456 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000102
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg2:   000000006a694554 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000010
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg3:   00000000fd00d27f <Obj>           Buffer(4) 00 10 52 44
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: 
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20230331/psparse-529)
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230331/dsfield-184)
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20230331/dswload2-477)
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: 
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_DSM]
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: 
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: Initialized Arguments for Method [_DSM]:  (4 arguments defined for method invocation)
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg0:   00000000fd00d27f <Obj>           Buffer(16) 75 0B A5 D4 C7 65 F7 46
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg1:   000000006a694554 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000102
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg2:   00000000152e7456 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000010
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg3:   000000007bb83016 <Obj>           Buffer(4) 00 20 52 44
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: 
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20230331/psparse-529)
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230331/dsfield-184)
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20230331/dswload2-477)
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: 
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_DSM]
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: 
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: Initialized Arguments for Method [_DSM]:  (4 arguments defined for method invocation)
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg0:   000000007bb83016 <Obj>           Buffer(16) 75 0B A5 D4 C7 65 F7 46
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg1:   00000000152e7456 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000102
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg2:   000000006a694554 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000010
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg3:   00000000fd00d27f <Obj>           Buffer(4) 00 30 52 44
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: 
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20230331/psparse-529)
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230331/dsfield-184)
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20230331/dswload2-477)
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: 
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_DSM]
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: 
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: Initialized Arguments for Method [_DSM]:  (4 arguments defined for method invocation)
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg0:   00000000fd00d27f <Obj>           Buffer(16) 75 0B A5 D4 C7 65 F7 46
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg1:   000000006a694554 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000102
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg2:   00000000152e7456 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000010
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg3:   000000007bb83016 <Obj>           Buffer(4) 00 40 52 44
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: 
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20230331/psparse-529)
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230331/dsfield-184)
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20230331/dswload2-477)
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: 
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_DSM]
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: 
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: Initialized Arguments for Method [_DSM]:  (4 arguments defined for method invocation)
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg0:   000000007bb83016 <Obj>           Buffer(16) 75 0B A5 D4 C7 65 F7 46
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg1:   00000000152e7456 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000102
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg2:   000000006a694554 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000010
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg3:   00000000fd00d27f <Obj>           Buffer(4) 00 50 52 44
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: 
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20230331/psparse-529)
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230331/dsfield-184)
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20230331/dswload2-477)
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: 
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_DSM]
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: 
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: Initialized Arguments for Method [_DSM]:  (4 arguments defined for method invocation)
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg0:   00000000fd00d27f <Obj>           Buffer(16) 75 0B A5 D4 C7 65 F7 46
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg1:   000000006a694554 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000102
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg2:   00000000152e7456 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000010
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg3:   000000007bb83016 <Obj>           Buffer(4) 00 60 52 44
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: 
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20230331/psparse-529)
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230331/dsfield-184)
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20230331/dswload2-477)
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: 
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_DSM]
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: 
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: Initialized Arguments for Method [_DSM]:  (4 arguments defined for method invocation)
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg0:   000000007bb83016 <Obj>           Buffer(16) 75 0B A5 D4 C7 65 F7 46
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg1:   00000000152e7456 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000102
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg2:   000000006a694554 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000010
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg3:   00000000fd00d27f <Obj>           Buffer(4) 00 70 52 44
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: 
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20230331/psparse-529)
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230331/dsfield-184)
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20230331/dswload2-477)
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: 
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_DSM]
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: 
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: Initialized Arguments for Method [_DSM]:  (4 arguments defined for method invocation)
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg0:   00000000fd00d27f <Obj>           Buffer(16) 75 0B A5 D4 C7 65 F7 46
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg1:   000000006a694554 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000102
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg2:   00000000152e7456 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000010
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg3:   000000007bb83016 <Obj>           Buffer(4) 00 80 52 44
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: 
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20230331/psparse-529)
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230331/dsfield-184)
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20230331/dswload2-477)
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: 
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_DSM]
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: 
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: Initialized Arguments for Method [_DSM]:  (4 arguments defined for method invocation)
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg0:   000000007bb83016 <Obj>           Buffer(16) 75 0B A5 D4 C7 65 F7 46
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg1:   00000000152e7456 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000102
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg2:   000000006a694554 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000010
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg3:   00000000fd00d27f <Obj>           Buffer(4) 00 90 52 44
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: 
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20230331/psparse-529)
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230331/dsfield-184)
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20230331/dswload2-477)
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: 
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_DSM]
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: 
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: Initialized Arguments for Method [_DSM]:  (4 arguments defined for method invocation)
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg0:   00000000fd00d27f <Obj>           Buffer(16) 75 0B A5 D4 C7 65 F7 46
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg1:   000000006a694554 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000102
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg2:   00000000152e7456 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000010
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg3:   000000007bb83016 <Obj>           Buffer(4) 00 A0 52 44
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: 
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20230331/psparse-529)
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230331/dsfield-184)
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20230331/dswload2-477)
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: 
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_DSM]
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: 
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: Initialized Arguments for Method [_DSM]:  (4 arguments defined for method invocation)
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg0:   000000007bb83016 <Obj>           Buffer(16) 75 0B A5 D4 C7 65 F7 46
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg1:   00000000152e7456 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000102
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg2:   000000006a694554 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000010
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg3:   00000000fd00d27f <Obj>           Buffer(4) 00 B0 52 44
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: 
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20230331/psparse-529)
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230331/dsfield-184)
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20230331/dswload2-477)
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: 
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_DSM]
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: 
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: Initialized Arguments for Method [_DSM]:  (4 arguments defined for method invocation)
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg0:   00000000fd00d27f <Obj>           Buffer(16) 75 0B A5 D4 C7 65 F7 46
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg1:   000000006a694554 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000102
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg2:   00000000152e7456 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000010
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg3:   000000007bb83016 <Obj>           Buffer(4) 00 C0 52 44
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: 
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20230331/psparse-529)
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230331/dsfield-184)
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20230331/dswload2-477)
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: 
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_DSM]
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: 
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: Initialized Arguments for Method [_DSM]:  (4 arguments defined for method invocation)
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg0:   000000007bb83016 <Obj>           Buffer(16) 75 0B A5 D4 C7 65 F7 46
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg1:   00000000152e7456 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000102
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg2:   000000006a694554 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000010
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg3:   00000000fd00d27f <Obj>           Buffer(4) 00 D0 52 44
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: 
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20230331/psparse-529)
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230331/dsfield-184)
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20230331/dswload2-477)
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: 
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_DSM]
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: 
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: Initialized Arguments for Method [_DSM]:  (4 arguments defined for method invocation)
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg0:   00000000fd00d27f <Obj>           Buffer(16) 75 0B A5 D4 C7 65 F7 46
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg1:   000000006a694554 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000102
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg2:   00000000152e7456 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000010
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg3:   000000007bb83016 <Obj>           Buffer(4) 00 E0 52 44
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: 
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20230331/psparse-529)
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230331/dsfield-184)
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20230331/dswload2-477)
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: 
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_DSM]
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: 
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: Initialized Arguments for Method [_DSM]:  (4 arguments defined for method invocation)
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg0:   000000007bb83016 <Obj>           Buffer(16) 75 0B A5 D4 C7 65 F7 46
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg1:   00000000152e7456 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000102
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg2:   000000006a694554 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000010
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg3:   00000000fd00d27f <Obj>           Buffer(4) 00 F0 52 44
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: 
Feb 10 12:31:42 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20230331/psparse-529)
Feb 10 12:31:43 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230331/dsfield-184)
Feb 10 12:31:43 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20230331/dswload2-477)
Feb 10 12:31:43 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: 
Feb 10 12:31:43 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_DSM]
Feb 10 12:31:43 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: 
Feb 10 12:31:43 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: Initialized Arguments for Method [_DSM]:  (4 arguments defined for method invocation)
Feb 10 12:31:43 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg0:   0000000038214f6e <Obj>           Buffer(16) 75 0B A5 D4 C7 65 F7 46
Feb 10 12:31:43 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg1:   00000000eecda26a <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000102
Feb 10 12:31:43 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg2:   0000000096150e25 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000010
Feb 10 12:31:43 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg3:   000000008fccfc47 <Obj>           Buffer(4) 00 00 4B 56
Feb 10 12:31:43 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: 
Feb 10 12:31:43 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20230331/psparse-529)
Feb 10 12:31:43 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230331/dsfield-184)
Feb 10 12:31:43 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20230331/dswload2-477)
Feb 10 12:31:43 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: 
Feb 10 12:31:43 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_DSM]
Feb 10 12:31:43 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: 
Feb 10 12:31:43 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: Initialized Arguments for Method [_DSM]:  (4 arguments defined for method invocation)
Feb 10 12:31:43 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg0:   000000005c7cd593 <Obj>           Buffer(16) 75 0B A5 D4 C7 65 F7 46
Feb 10 12:31:43 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg1:   000000009139c931 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000102
Feb 10 12:31:43 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg2:   00000000bece3bb2 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000010
Feb 10 12:31:43 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel:   Arg3:   0000000023b78742 <Obj>           Buffer(4) 00 00 50 4F
Feb 10 12:31:43 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: 
Feb 10 12:31:43 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20230331/psparse-529)
Feb 10 12:31:43 felix-ubuntu-lm kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Malformed MSFT vendor event: 0x02
```

Comment: What are you using to install the Nvidia driver and is it the right version? Try https://askubuntu.com/q/1258904/1004020

Comment: Sudo apt install nividia-driver-xxx or over the additional driver GUI, does not make a difference. Nvidia recommends 530, ubuntu 470, and I also tried 545. I see that it is working when I press at the grey screen Ctrl alt f2 and nvidia-smi, but it does not boot.

Comment: When the driver was working it put the Login mask on the second connected display. Well..

Comment: Can you post a picture of what kind of "grey screen" it is?