# NVIDIA driver error: assignment of read-only member ‘vm_flags’

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, graphics, cuda

I installed NVIDIA driver based on [this suggesiton](https://askubuntu.com/a/1258909/) using the following command:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

The above command installed `nvidia-driver-535 (535.154.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1)` and other tools. Next, I tried installing CUDA but the installer throws the following error:

```
Loading new nvidia-520.61.05 DKMS files...
Building for 6.2.0-39-generic 6.5.0-18-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 6.2.0-39-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/nvidia-dkms-520.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.2.0-39-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/520.61.05/build/make.log for more information.
```

I looked at the crash file and found the following errors:

```
 /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/520.61.05/build/nvidia/nv-mmap.c: In function ‘nvidia_mmap_numa’:
 /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/520.61.05/build/nvidia/nv-mmap.c:446:19: error: assignment of read-only member ‘vm_flags’
   446 |     vma->vm_flags |= VM_MIXEDMAP;
       |                   ^~
 /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/520.61.05/build/nvidia/nv-mmap.c: In function ‘nvidia_mmap_helper’:
```

The [crash](https://pastebin.com/HfSNVWdn) and [log](https://pastebin.com/rZrAsX4K) files are uploaded to Pastebin.

Below is the enviroment information:

```
$ lspci | grep -i nvidia
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA102 [GeForce RTX 3090] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GA102 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

$ ldd --version
ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.35-0ubuntu3.6) 2.35
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.

$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ uname -a
Linux asus 6.2.0-39-generic #40~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Nov 16 10:53:04 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ nvidia-detector
nvidia-driver-545

$ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
wayland
```

I found that this issue has been reported at [here](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/driver-470-182-03-fails-to-compile-with-linux-6-3-1/251992), [here](https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/CR55BD4YCDR1.22R5TLYJW6YS0@vincent-arch/t/), and [here](https://github.com/NVIDIA/open-gpu-kernel-modules/issues/469). but they reported it with kernel 6.3, however I am using 6.2.

What is the workaround?

Comment: I found a workaround by installing CUDA 12.3 on kernel 6.5.0-18-generic. Thank you very much

Comment: if your are kind can you post it here  ?

Comment: @CorneaValentin: What do want me to post? I can post it in easy to understand manner based on your comment

Comment: nvm , i was made a fresh install of ubuntu now it's work , maybe was am issue due older kernels i had ... or video driver .. now i got working on 12.3 cuda with 545 driver

Comment: @CorneaValentin: Good to hear about it. What I found that for 12.3 CUDA you need kernel 6.5.0-18-generic and NVIDIA 545 driver. I posted detailed info [here](https://ravijo.github.io/cuda/)

Comment: yes , ubuntu 22.04.04 LTS came with that kernel