# Ubuntu not booting due to iwlwifi error-WRT: Invalid buffer destination

Tags: boot, networking, 22.04, startup

I updated Ubuntu 22.04.4 to 6.5.0-21 kernel update, since then I am unable to boot up into Ubuntu. While boot up, there is the error `iwlwifi WRT: Invalid buffer destination`
I tried to boot into [recovery mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode), but without success (loop in "Starting Network Time Synchronization").

I got a black screen with the following messages.

```
[   0.004260] __common_interrupt: 1.55 No irq handler for vector
[   0.004260] __common_interrupt: 2.55 No irq handler for vector
[   0.004260] __common_interrupt: 3.55 No irq handler for vector
[   0.004260] __common_interrupt: 4.55 No irq handler for vector
[   0.004260] __common_interrupt: 5.55 No irq handler for vector
[   0.004260] __common_interrupt: 6.55 No irq handler for vector
[   0.004260] __common_interrupt: 7.55 No irq handler for vector
[   0.004260] __common_interrupt: 8.55 No irq handler for vector
[   0.004260] __common_interrupt: 9.55 No irq handler for vector
[   0.004260] __common_interrupt: 10.55 No irq handler for vector
[   5.301695] 
[  12.505302] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: WRT: Invalid buffer destination
_
```

What can I do now?

Comment: iwlwifi is not what's breaking boot. Are you on Nvidia?

Comment: Yes I have Nvidia GPU

Comment: Go to the Ctrl+Alt+F1 TTY and log in. Then install the correct Nvidia driver version for the new kernel version with https://askubuntu.com/q/1258904/1004020 . If it still doesn't work, downgrade the kernel from 6.5 HWE to 5.15 GA

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+F1 doesn't send me to a tty.  Ctrl+Alt+F3 does.

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+F1 is meant to be used when you see the iwlwifi error, not at GRUB. If it's not responding, you can try Alt+PrintScreen then R then Ctrl+Alt+F1

Comment: How can I downgrade the kernel from 6.5 HWE to 5.15 GA?

Comment: `sudo apt install linux-generic ; sudo apt remove linux-generic-hwe-22.04 ; sudo apt autoremove`

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack and searching "*To downgrade from HWE/OEM to GA kernel*" tells you how... multiple kernel stacks can co-exist on an install too (ie. removing HWE is *optional*) except for when some closed source kernel modules prevent it (eg. some nvidia won't allow multiple stacks co-existing)

Comment: If I switch from HWE/OEM kernel to GA kernel, will I lose all the configuration (IP address, VNC server, ...)

Comment: No, switching the kernel will not affect userspace. Userspace includes that "IP address, VNC server". The kernel includes the drivers but no configuration

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop using the HWE kernel and go back to the GA kernel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1306358/how-to-stop-using-the-hwe-kernel-and-go-back-to-the-ga-kernel)

Comment: No. I remove all NVIDIA Drivers (Se: https://askubuntu.com/questions/206283/how-can-i-uninstall-a-nvidia-driver-completely/206289#206289), Reboot and  install the correct Nvidia driver version for the new kernel version.

Comment: In French: https://zonetuto.fr/linux/ubuntu-comment-desinstaller-completement-un-pilote-nvidia/

Answer (score 0):

Just solved a similar problem. Some how in the power settings my Automatic Suspend settings was changed to plugged- in and should be When on Battery. Apparently the program I am running is not able to let my os know it running.
Check your Power settings!