# Im having trouble booting Ubuntu on dual boot

Tags: boot, drivers, dual-boot, grub2, iwlwifi

### i keeps having the following issues:

```
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: invalid buffer destination
```

My GPU is: intel(R) xe graphics

**I have already tried this from ask Ubuntu**: [Ubuntu not booting due to iwlwifi error-WRT: Invalid buffer destination](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1506164/ubuntu-not-booting-due-to-iwlwifi-error-wrt-invalid-buffer-destination)
But didn't seems to work.

> i could not even go to tty. But going to tty2-6 is fine and can be able to login smoothly