Ubuntu not booting due to several error-messages
I bought the new HP Omen Transcend 14 with an Intel Core Ultra 9 processor, 32 GB RAM and an Nvidia RTX4070 graphics card. I am a total Ubuntu beginner and need Ubuntu 22.04 LTS for university. After I had created a USB stick from which I installed Ubuntu 22.04, I received several error messages during the reboot. The error messages (see picture) remain for 10 minutes and then only a black screen with a flashing cursor can be seen.
error messages
I have downloaded all nvidia drivers that are recommended.
I would be very grateful if someone could help me..

Try some of the suggestions in this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1506164/ubuntu-not-booting-due-to-iwlwifi-error-wrt-invalid-buffer-destination
