# Unable to Install Cuda Drivers on ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda

Trying to install nvidia drivers on my ubuntu server. Running `nvidia-smi` after install and reboot yields the following:

```
nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

My Ubuntu version is:

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available. 
Distributor ID: Ubuntu 
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release:        22.04 
Codename:       jammy
```

The server is a penguin computing gpu server, with several different tesla cards installed. (Penguin Computing / Gigabyte MG50-G20 2U 8x GPU E5-2600v3/v4 Graphics Server)

Examining the `/proc/driver/` folder shows no nvidia sub folder.

Driver was installed via the following command:

`sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-440-server`

I have also tried using the different drivers and have rebooted after each time (545, 440, and the non server versions)

Have purged nvidia installs and run `autoremove`. Have tried installing nvidia toolkit directly using this guide to encounter the same error https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&Distribution=Ubuntu&target_version=22.04&target_type=deb_local

Trying to use the ubuntu-drivers util doesn't work either,

But upon running sudo ubuntu-drivers install nvidia-driver, I get

No drivers found for installation.

Running lspci yields the following

```
    lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D DMI2 (rev 01)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 01)
00:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 01)
00:03.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev 01)
00:05.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Map/VTd_Misc/System Management (rev 01)
00:05.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D IIO Hot Plug (rev 01)
00:05.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D IIO RAS/Control Status/Global Errors (rev 01)
00:05.4 PIC: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D I/O APIC (rev 01)
00:11.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Intel Corporation C610/X99 series chipset SPSR (rev 05)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation C610/X99 series chipset USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 05)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation C610/X99 series chipset MEI Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:16.1 Communication controller: Intel Corporation C610/X99 series chipset MEI Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation C610/X99 series chipset USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation C610/X99 series chipset PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d5)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation C610/X99 series chipset PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d5)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation C610/X99 series chipset PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev d5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation C610/X99 series chipset USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation C610/X99 series chipset LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation C610/X99 series chipset SMBus Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation C610/X99 series chipset Thermal Subsystem (rev 05)
01:00.0 Serial Attached SCSI controller: Broadcom / LSI SAS2308 PCI-Express Fusion-MPT SAS-2 (rev 05)
02:00.0 PCI bridge: PLX Technology, Inc. PEX 8747 48-Lane, 5-Port PCI Express Gen 3 (8.0 GT/s) Switch (rev ca)
03:08.0 PCI bridge: PLX Technology, Inc. PEX 8747 48-Lane, 5-Port PCI Express Gen 3 (8.0 GT/s) Switch (rev ca)
03:10.0 PCI bridge: PLX Technology, Inc. PEX 8747 48-Lane, 5-Port PCI Express Gen 3 (8.0 GT/s) Switch (rev ca)
06:00.0 PCI bridge: PLX Technology, Inc. PEX 8747 48-Lane, 5-Port PCI Express Gen 3 (8.0 GT/s) Switch (rev ca)
07:08.0 PCI bridge: PLX Technology, Inc. PEX 8747 48-Lane, 5-Port PCI Express Gen 3 (8.0 GT/s) Switch (rev ca)
07:10.0 PCI bridge: PLX Technology, Inc. PEX 8747 48-Lane, 5-Port PCI Express Gen 3 (8.0 GT/s) Switch (rev ca)
0b:00.0 PCI bridge: ASPEED Technology, Inc. AST1150 PCI-to-PCI Bridge (rev 03)
0c:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ASPEED Technology, Inc. ASPEED Graphics Family (rev 30)
0d:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection (rev 01)
0d:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection (rev 01)
7f:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D QPI Link 0 (rev 01)
7f:08.2 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D QPI Link 0 (rev 01)
7f:08.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D QPI Link 0 (rev 01)
7f:09.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D QPI Link 1 (rev 01)
7f:09.2 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D QPI Link 1 (rev 01)
7f:09.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D QPI Link 1 (rev 01)
7f:0b.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D R3 QPI Link 0/1 (rev 01)
7f:0b.1 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D R3 QPI Link 0/1 (rev 01)
7f:0b.2 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D R3 QPI Link 0/1 (rev 01)
7f:0b.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D R3 QPI Link Debug (rev 01)
7f:0c.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Caching Agent (rev 01)
7f:0c.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Caching Agent (rev 01)
7f:0c.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Caching Agent (rev 01)
7f:0c.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Caching Agent (rev 01)
7f:0c.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Caching Agent (rev 01)
7f:0c.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Caching Agent (rev 01)
7f:0c.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Caching Agent (rev 01)
7f:0c.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Caching Agent (rev 01)
7f:0d.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Caching Agent (rev 01)
7f:0d.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Caching Agent (rev 01)
7f:0d.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Caching Agent (rev 01)
7f:0d.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Caching Agent (rev 01)
7f:0d.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Caching Agent (rev 01)
7f:0d.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Caching Agent (rev 01)
7f:0f.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Caching Agent (rev 01)
7f:0f.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Caching Agent (rev 01)
7f:0f.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Caching Agent (rev 01)
7f:0f.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Caching Agent (rev 01)
7f:0f.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Caching Agent (rev 01)
7f:0f.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Caching Agent (rev 01)
7f:0f.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Caching Agent (rev 01)
7f:10.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D R2PCIe Agent (rev 01)
7f:10.1 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D R2PCIe Agent (rev 01)
7f:10.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Ubox (rev 01)
7f:10.6 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Ubox (rev 01)
7f:10.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Ubox (rev 01)
7f:12.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Home Agent 0 (rev 01)
7f:12.1 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Home Agent 0 (rev 01)
7f:12.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Home Agent 1 (rev 01)
7f:12.5 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Home Agent 1 (rev 01)
7f:13.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Memory Controller 0 - Target Address/Thermal/RAS (rev 01)
7f:13.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Memory Controller 0 - Target Address/Thermal/RAS (rev 01)
7f:13.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Memory Controller 0 - Channel Target Address Decoder (rev 01)
7f:13.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Memory Controller 0 - Channel Target Address Decoder (rev 01)
7f:13.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D DDRIO Channel 0/1 Broadcast (rev 01)
7f:13.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D DDRIO Global Broadcast (rev 01)
7f:14.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Memory Controller 0 - Channel 0 Thermal Control (rev 01)
7f:14.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Memory Controller 0 - Channel 1 Thermal Control (rev 01)
7f:14.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Memory Controller 0 - Channel 0 Error (rev 01)
7f:14.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Memory Controller 0 - Channel 1 Error (rev 01)
7f:14.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D DDRIO Channel 0/1 Interface (rev 01)
7f:14.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D DDRIO Channel 0/1 Interface (rev 01)
7f:14.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D DDRIO Channel 0/1 Interface (rev 01)
7f:14.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D DDRIO Channel 0/1 Interface (rev 01)
7f:16.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Target Address/Thermal/RAS (rev 01)
7f:16.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Target Address/Thermal/RAS (rev 01)
7f:16.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Channel Target Address Decoder (rev 01)
7f:16.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Channel Target Address Decoder (rev 01)
7f:16.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D DDRIO Channel 2/3 Broadcast (rev 01)
7f:16.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D DDRIO Global Broadcast (rev 01)
7f:17.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Memory Controller 1 - Channel 0 Thermal Control (rev 01)
7f:17.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Memory Controller 1 - Channel 1 Thermal Control (rev 01)
7f:17.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Memory Controller 1 - Channel 0 Error (rev 01)
7f:17.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Memory Controller 1 - Channel 1 Error (rev 01)
7f:17.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D DDRIO Channel 2/3 Interface (rev 01)
7f:17.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D DDRIO Channel 2/3 Interface (rev 01)
7f:17.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D DDRIO Channel 2/3 Interface (rev 01)
7f:17.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D DDRIO Channel 2/3 Interface (rev 01)
7f:1e.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Power Control Unit (rev 01)
7f:1e.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Power Control Unit (rev 01)
7f:1e.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Power Control Unit (rev 01)
7f:1e.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Power Control Unit (rev 01)
7f:1e.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Power Control Unit (rev 01)
7f:1f.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Power Control Unit (rev 01)
7f:1f.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Power Control Unit (rev 01)
80:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 01)
80:03.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev 01)
80:05.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Map/VTd_Misc/System Management (rev 01)
80:05.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D IIO Hot Plug (rev 01)
80:05.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D IIO RAS/Control Status/Global Errors (rev 01)
80:05.4 PIC: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D I/O APIC (rev 01)
81:00.0 PCI bridge: PLX Technology, Inc. PEX 8747 48-Lane, 5-Port PCI Express Gen 3 (8.0 GT/s) Switch (rev ca)
82:08.0 PCI bridge: PLX Technology, Inc. PEX 8747 48-Lane, 5-Port PCI Express Gen 3 (8.0 GT/s) Switch (rev ca)
82:10.0 PCI bridge: PLX Technology, Inc. PEX 8747 48-Lane, 5-Port PCI Express Gen 3 (8.0 GT/s) Switch (rev ca)
85:00.0 PCI bridge: PLX Technology, Inc. PEX 8747 48-Lane, 5-Port PCI Express Gen 3 (8.0 GT/s) Switch (rev ca)
86:08.0 PCI bridge: PLX Technology, Inc. PEX 8747 48-Lane, 5-Port PCI Express Gen 3 (8.0 GT/s) Switch (rev ca)
86:10.0 PCI bridge: PLX Technology, Inc. PEX 8747 48-Lane, 5-Port PCI Express Gen 3 (8.0 GT/s) Switch (rev ca)
88:00.0 PCI bridge: PLX Technology, Inc. PEX 8747 48-Lane, 5-Port PCI Express Gen 3 (8.0 GT/s) Switch (rev ca)
89:08.0 PCI bridge: PLX Technology, Inc. PEX 8747 48-Lane, 5-Port PCI Express Gen 3 (8.0 GT/s) Switch (rev ca)
89:09.0 PCI bridge: PLX Technology, Inc. PEX 8747 48-Lane, 5-Port PCI Express Gen 3 (8.0 GT/s) Switch (rev ca)
89:10.0 PCI bridge: PLX Technology, Inc. PEX 8747 48-Lane, 5-Port PCI Express Gen 3 (8.0 GT/s) Switch (rev ca)
89:11.0 PCI bridge: PLX Technology, Inc. PEX 8747 48-Lane, 5-Port PCI Express Gen 3 (8.0 GT/s) Switch (rev ca)
ff:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D QPI Link 0 (rev 01)
ff:08.2 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D QPI Link 0 (rev 01)
ff:08.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D QPI Link 0 (rev 01)
ff:09.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D QPI Link 1 (rev 01)
ff:09.2 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D QPI Link 1 (rev 01)
ff:09.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D QPI Link 1 (rev 01)
ff:0b.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D R3 QPI Link 0/1 (rev 01)
ff:0b.1 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D R3 QPI Link 0/1 (rev 01)
ff:0b.2 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D R3 QPI Link 0/1 (rev 01)
ff:0b.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D R3 QPI Link Debug (rev 01)
ff:0c.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Caching Agent (rev 01)
ff:0c.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Caching Agent (rev 01)
ff:0c.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Caching Agent (rev 01)
ff:0c.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Caching Agent (rev 01)
ff:0c.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Caching Agent (rev 01)
ff:0c.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Caching Agent (rev 01)
ff:0c.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Caching Agent (rev 01)
ff:0c.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Caching Agent (rev 01)
ff:0d.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Caching Agent (rev 01)
ff:0d.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Caching Agent (rev 01)
ff:0d.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Caching Agent (rev 01)
ff:0d.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Caching Agent (rev 01)
ff:0d.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Caching Agent (rev 01)
ff:0d.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Caching Agent (rev 01)
ff:0f.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Caching Agent (rev 01)
ff:0f.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Caching Agent (rev 01)
ff:0f.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Caching Agent (rev 01)
ff:0f.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Caching Agent (rev 01)
ff:0f.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Caching Agent (rev 01)
ff:0f.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Caching Agent (rev 01)
ff:0f.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Caching Agent (rev 01)
ff:10.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D R2PCIe Agent (rev 01)
ff:10.1 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D R2PCIe Agent (rev 01)
ff:10.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Ubox (rev 01)
ff:10.6 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Ubox (rev 01)
ff:10.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Ubox (rev 01)
ff:12.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Home Agent 0 (rev 01)
ff:12.1 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Home Agent 0 (rev 01)
ff:12.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Home Agent 1 (rev 01)
ff:12.5 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Home Agent 1 (rev 01)
ff:13.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Memory Controller 0 - Target Address/Thermal/RAS (rev 01)
ff:13.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Memory Controller 0 - Target Address/Thermal/RAS (rev 01)
ff:13.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Memory Controller 0 - Channel Target Address Decoder (rev 01)
ff:13.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Memory Controller 0 - Channel Target Address Decoder (rev 01)
ff:13.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D DDRIO Channel 0/1 Broadcast (rev 01)
ff:13.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D DDRIO Global Broadcast (rev 01)
ff:14.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Memory Controller 0 - Channel 0 Thermal Control (rev 01)
ff:14.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Memory Controller 0 - Channel 1 Thermal Control (rev 01)
ff:14.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Memory Controller 0 - Channel 0 Error (rev 01)
ff:14.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Memory Controller 0 - Channel 1 Error (rev 01)
ff:14.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D DDRIO Channel 0/1 Interface (rev 01)
ff:14.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D DDRIO Channel 0/1 Interface (rev 01)
ff:14.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D DDRIO Channel 0/1 Interface (rev 01)
ff:14.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D DDRIO Channel 0/1 Interface (rev 01)
ff:16.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Target Address/Thermal/RAS (rev 01)
ff:16.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Target Address/Thermal/RAS (rev 01)
ff:16.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Channel Target Address Decoder (rev 01)
ff:16.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Channel Target Address Decoder (rev 01)
ff:16.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D DDRIO Channel 2/3 Broadcast (rev 01)
ff:16.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D DDRIO Global Broadcast (rev 01)
ff:17.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Memory Controller 1 - Channel 0 Thermal Control (rev 01)
ff:17.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Memory Controller 1 - Channel 1 Thermal Control (rev 01)
ff:17.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Memory Controller 1 - Channel 0 Error (rev 01)
ff:17.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Memory Controller 1 - Channel 1 Error (rev 01)
ff:17.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D DDRIO Channel 2/3 Interface (rev 01)
ff:17.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D DDRIO Channel 2/3 Interface (rev 01)
ff:17.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D DDRIO Channel 2/3 Interface (rev 01)
ff:17.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D DDRIO Channel 2/3 Interface (rev 01)
ff:1e.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Power Control Unit (rev 01)
ff:1e.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Power Control Unit (rev 01)
ff:1e.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Power Control Unit (rev 01)
ff:1e.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Power Control Unit (rev 01)
ff:1e.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Power Control Unit (rev 01)
ff:1f.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Power Control Unit (rev 01)
ff:1f.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Power Control Unit (rev 01)
```

```
sudo dmesg | grep 'nvidia'
[   18.651587] audit: type=1400 audit(1709416236.572:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe" pid=1288 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   18.651603] audit: type=1400 audit(1709416236.572:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe//kmod" pid=1288 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  171.597622] audit: type=1400 audit(1709416389.797:151): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe" pid=1873 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  171.597625] audit: type=1400 audit(1709416389.797:152): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe//kmod" pid=1873 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  323.657965] audit: type=1400 audit(1709416541.857:191): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe" pid=3981 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  323.657968] audit: type=1400 audit(1709416541.857:192): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe//kmod" pid=3981 comm="apparmor_parser"
```

Comment: There is an automatic way to know which driver you need: https://askubuntu.com/q/1258904/1004020

Comment: Please [edit] with `lspci` . If this is a specialized Penguin Computing Server, then you might need to go to their website to ask for help. The drivers in the Ubuntu repositories are mostly targeted for gaming GPUs

Comment: I did not see any Nvidia hardware in your `lspci` . Are you sure that server has a GPU? If there were errors discovering the GPU, you would find them in `dmesg`

Comment: There are 6 telsa cards connected via pci adapters, i think the adapters show up in the lspci but not the actual cards themselves. I grepped for nviida and posted the contents from dmesg, i would post the total output but its 43 pages

Comment: No, nvidia_modprobe in dmesg does not mean you have a Nvidia GPU. It's only saying that you are launching Nvidia software, regardless if that Nvidia software is able to find any Nvidia hardware.