# 20.04 Focal - Nvidia driver no longer loading with kernel 5.4.0-42

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel

On Ubuntu 20.04 Focal, I upgraded to kernel `5.4.0-42` (using the Software Updater GUI / apt) and my Nvidia proprietary drivers stopped working.

Rebooting to the old kernel (`5.4.0-40`) yields a working system, so it is clear that the kernel update was the trigger for the problem.

I did all the usual things of ensuring that nouveau was blacklisted and updating ramfs. I also purged all nvidia packages from apt and reinstalled. No luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For some reason, the headers for `5.4.0-42` weren't installed by apt automatically. (I did the original offending kernel update as part of a prompt from the "Software Updater" GUI.)

Installing the headers with:

```
sudo apt install linux-headers-5.4.0-42-generic
```

caused apt to automatically recompile the nvidia kernel module for the new kernel. After a reboot to the new kernel, everything just worked.

I'm not sure why headers weren't installed automatically (I believe they usually are?). Perhaps there is a problem with the apt package for the new kernel? (It was released 2 days ago as of this post.)

This happened on the **20.04 Focal** release.

**Update:**

Per the comments below, the `linux-headers-generic` metapackage (and the `linux-generic` metapackage) was not installed on my system. It looks like they were removed on the day that I upgraded to Focal. It happened around the time of removing an old Nvidia driver.

Comment: The reason why the headers didn't install may be that meta package `linux-headers-generic` is not installed for some reason.

Comment: install meta-package linux-generic. then both will be drawn; during upgrade from linux-generic package.

Comment: Interesting! @Pilot6 @nobody -- thank you! Indeed, `linux-headers-generic` was not installed. Looking at /var/log/dpkg.log, it looks like it was removed on the day I upgraded to Focal. (I certainly did not remove it on purpose). Log here: https://gist.github.com/joelrbrandt/9c324d1d1192e6c8098f4e789c99affe

Comment: Thank you! This worked for  me after a kernel update to 5.4.0.51-generic occured on a system that had previously been upgrade from ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04.