# Nvidia driver are not working

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg

I'm running on 22.04.1.
I tried to install driver via GUI, the system was clean from any previous installation,
but after reboot I am still running at super low resolution like with default drivers.
if I go via GUI to the driver menu, it tells me I am on the right drivers now but effectively the nvidia control panel is not showing me anything about the gpu. drivers are installed but NOT working basically.
I have a rtx 4090.
drivers version 520 were working fine before an update broke other OS components ([read here for more details)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1444222/network-not-working-after-ubuntu-system-update)

purging all nvidia drivers again and reinstalling them from GUI looks like is ineffective.

UPDATE:

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running
```

I already tried this, and it doesn't work:
[other similar case](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1153023/error-nvidia-driver-is-not-loaded?rq=1)