# Issue with nvidia drivers after laptop closed unexpectedly

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, hp

I was working in my laptop and suddenly it just went off.
When i reopened it directly gave a message of `CMOS RESET 502` and it closed again.

I reopened after an hour and this message didn't appear but the issue now is that my gpu feels (from the heat and the fans going crazy) that it is running on 100%. And I am saying feels cause `nvidia-smi` doesnt work anymore as it gives:

> NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA
> driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and
> running.

Also:
`>>>nvidia-settings -q GPUUtilization -q useddedicatedgpumemory` gives:

> ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded

Also:

```
>>>nvidia-settings
ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded


ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system


(nvidia-settings:8255): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 20:06:12.090: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
```

Some info:

`>>>lsb_release -a` --> `Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS`

`>>>lspci | grep VGA` --> `01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1f50 (rev a1`

```
>>>dkms status 
   nvidia, 470.161.03, 5.4.0-139-generic, x86_64: installed
   nvidia, 470.161.03, 5.4.0-144-generic, x86_64: installed
   v4l2loopback, 0.10.0, 5.4.0-139-generic, x86_64: installed
   v4l2loopback, 0.10.0, 5.4.0-144-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Tried from this [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1153023/error-nvidia-driver-is-not-loaded) but failed with message that DbDriver is locked by another process:

```
>>> sudo dpkg-reconfigure nvidia-dkms-470
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

I also run the following (from @karen comment source):

```
>>>sudo fuser -v /var/cache/debconf/config.dat
/var/cache/debconf/config.dat:
                     root       9187 F.... frontend
```

`frontend` process which seems that is something that I am on secure boot related.

Any idea why is this happening? Is it only gpu or the OS is corrupted? How could i validate whats happening?

Thanks in advance

**Edit**

I managed to make it work by disabling the secure boot. But I dont get it why is this happening and how can I avoid the issue without disabling the secure boot?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["debconf: DbDriver "config": config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable" while installing packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136881/debconf-dbdriver-config-config-dat-is-locked-by-another-process-resource-t)

Comment: @karel thanks for your reply. `frontend` process seems to be running. Should I kill it? I have updated my question for more clear view.

Comment: frontend is not boot related. frontend indicates some apt process such as `install` or `remove`. killing `frontend` permanently ends that apt process.

Comment: @karel so its fine to kill it?

Comment: Yes, its OK to kill it.